# .net 7 maui balzor firebase push notification

Tags: .net, firebase-cloud-messaging, maui-blazor

I don't want the one for .net 6 old version. The one for .net maui blazor is more necessary. new .net 7 maui app firebase push notification and authorization,

Comment: can you explain more what you need ?

Comment: .net 7 maui blazor hybrid project in use firebasse push notification code. (no xaml)

Comment: .net 7 maui blazor app firebase push notification and authorization,